# Improperly defined integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am currently trying to solve an integral in which, after finding the antiderivative, one of the limits contains $\ln(-a/a)$.

This seems to imply that the result is complex valued which is fine: $\ln(-1) = i \pi$.

What leaves me at a loss is that indeed all of these can be shown to be true:

$$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}_{0} \; \ln(-1)=\pm (k+1) i \pi$$

This term appears in an integral that describes a physical quantity. It matters, what sign and which absolute value this quantity has. I do realize that this question lacks substance, I am basically looking for advice on where to search.

Comment: Should be $~(2k+1)i\pi~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z},~$ so the $~\pm~$ sign unnecessary.

Comment: In order to define a complex logarithm, you first need to choose a determinantion, id est the range where your complex logarithm will take its values. It is possible that your physics problem already contains an implicit choice.

Comment: the argument of the integral runs from 0 to i infinity. The a in ln(-a/a) is real valued. The term I indicate here, ln(-a/a) is the result for the limit 0. Can I infer from this which branch I have to chose?